# Free-form metadata in Docbook

Tags: metadata, docbook, freeform

I'm looking to store some metadata in Docbook (V5) XML files. Specifically, links to various resources related to the article in question. I've found the `<info>` and related elements, but they do not quite fit my purpose.

Is there any way to store free-form metadata in a Docbook file? I really just want key/value pairs stored at the article level.

Thanks,
Kent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole set of Dublin Core is allowed in V5.
But if it's not inside , you will need to modify DB5 and create a variant, it's not insurmountable and described in Ch5 of The Definitive Guide (http://www.docbook.org/tdg5/en/html/ch05.html)

Lech